# blocks become hidden!

Tags: blocks, theming, 7

I created some blocks, and I assign them to regions for specific layout using context (and context_omega). now I can't see these assigned block in the admin/blocks. but I can see them being rendered, and I can edit them via URL. is it normal for context? or there's problem somewhere?
BTW I cleared the cache :)

Comment: You need to filter blocks per regions via the block module itself... it's one tab above the one who let's you filter them per NID... Just filter them via Content type (I use Context mostly to hide certain regions from certain Panels or content types), or else, I didn't understand the question. Ben.